# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "package_code_key"

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I have written a test case for create api in Django but I am getting the above error. I see in database it creates some objects and says that there is a duplicate key value in the error.

My model is:

```
class Example(models.Model):

    package = models.ForeignKey(
        Destination, related_name="packages", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="user_packages",
    )

    tour = models.ForeignKey(
        Tours,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="tour_packages",
    )
```

My test case is as follows:

```
import factory

# Define your factories
class PackageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'example.Destination'

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'example.User'

class TourFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'example.Tour'

class ExampleFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    package = factory.SubFactory(PackageFactory)
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    tour = factory.TourFactory(TourFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = 'example.Example'

# And now, create a new example instance together with all related models.
example = ExampleFactory()
```

I cleared the database and start running the test but I get the same error. How to solve this??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've made manually some changes in database (for example deleted you row) (like me with DBeaver)

All you need - it's to run one SQL query:

```
SELECT setval('"YOUR_TABLE_NAME_id_seq"',
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the factory definition you have:

```
class PackageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'example.Package'
```

This is using the model named 'example.Package' but in the Example model you have.

```
class Example(models.Model):

        package = models.ForeignKey(
            Destination, related_name="packages", on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
```

The ForeignKey is to the model Destination. Try changing the model in factory for Destination. If this in not the problem you should upload the others models that you are using.

Comment: sorry it was a typo. I edited my code. I have the same error with Destination on my source code.